# Install SQL Server 2005 on computer with an existing SQL Server 2008 installation

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a Windows XP 64 bit workstation. I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard x64. After that, I installed SQL Server 2005 Standard x64. Installation completed with no issues, but no instance was created. If I run 2005 or 2008 tools, there is no way of creating a 2005 instance. What do I need to do?

Since I am developing/testing databases for 2005 and 2008 SQL Server versions, then I need both versions installed in the same Workstation. Thanks for you support.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the 2008 with Default instance name, then you must have specified a name for the 2005 instance. Also, if you run the SQL Server Configuration Manager from the 2008 start menu, you should see two instances (or one, at least) and their statuses. If not, I hope you didn't over-wrote the 2008 instance with 2005. I doubt that's possible, though.

If Database Services were installed successfully during both installations, you should have two instances. If not, then the database services module must have failed.

I'm using 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 n my x64 Win 7 machine. I did installed the express editions and respected the version order for installing. But I call my 2005 instance `SQLExpress2005`, 2008 instance `SQLExpress2008`, and 2008 R2 `SQLExpress`.

And if you do find any instance, connect to it using 2008 Management studio and check the instance version against this: http://sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx

Comment: I removed SQL Server 2005, rebooted, and tried reinstalling it again (from the 2nd file). Only client components, tools, and books, are shown (not server or instance-specific options appear (like when I installed SQL Server 2008 R2). I am using 2 setup files I downloaded from the Microsoft Volumne Licensing site, they are called : SW_CD_SQL_Svr_Standard_Edtn_2005_64Bit_X64_English_1_x64_MLF_X11-57664.EXE, SW_CD_SQL_Svr_Standard_Edtn_2005_64Bit_X64_English_2_x64_MLF_X11-57665.EXE.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Windows XP 64 bit workstation. I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard x64.

Sounds like a bug in the installer, full server editions of SQL Server (except Developer) only run on server<sup>1</sup> editions of Windows. (Express editions also run on client Windows).

The requirements are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#SEx64 (Standard 64bit)

---

<sup>1</sup> WinXP 64 was derived WinXP 32 --> 2003 --> WinXP 64, so this case is more complex